# How to add a combobox to a kendogrid in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build a license grid that allows the user to select a license type as a combobox using a foreign key constraint

Here is where I try to build the grid in cshtml

```
@(
        Html.Kendo().Grid<IpdCustomerLicenseViewModel>()
            .Name("licenseGrid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.LicenseNumber).Title("License Number").Width(200);
                columns.Bound(p => p.ExpirationDate).Title("Expiration Date").Width(200);
                columns.Bound(p => p.IpdCustomerId).Hidden(true);
                columns.Bound(p => p.IpdCustomerLicenseTypeLookupId).Title("License Type").Width(200);
            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar =>
            {
                toolbar.Create().HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-disabled", Id = "createLicenseRequest" });
                toolbar.Save();
            })
            .AutoBind(true)
            .ColumnMenu(col => col.Filterable(true))
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
            .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(200))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 600px;" })
            .Events(x => x.Change("onLicenseChange").DataBound("onLicenseDataBound"))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Events(e => e.RequestEnd("onLicenseChange"))
                .Batch(true)
                .ServerOperation(false)
                .PageSize(50)
                .Model(model => { model.Id(p => p.Id); })
                .Update(update => update.Action("InsertLicenseInformation", "IpdCustomer").Data("additionalDataOnLicenseCreate"))
                .Create(create => create.Action("InsertLicenseInformation", "IpdCustomer").Data("additionalDataOnLicenseCreate"))
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetIpdCustomerLicenseGrid", "IpdCustomer").Data("additionalDataOnRead"))
            )
                )
```

These are my models:

```
namespace Exemplar.Models.IpdModels
{
    public class IpdCustomerLicense
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string? LicenseNumber { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int? IpdCustomerId { get; set; }
        
        public IpdCustomer? IpdCustomer { get; set; }

        public int? IpdCustomerLicenseTypeLookupId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IpdCustomerLicenseTypeLookup? IpdCustomerLicenseTypeLookup { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? UpdateDateTime { get; set; }

        public string? UpdateBy { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? InsertDateTime { get; set; }

        public string? InsertBy { get; set; }

    }

    public class IpdCustomerLicenseTypeLookup
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? UpdateDateTime { get; set; }

        public string? UpdateBy { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? InsertDateTime { get; set; }

        public string? InsertBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the view model:

```
public class IpdCustomerLicenseViewModel : Models.IpdModels.IpdCustomerLicense
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectList>? LicenseList { get; set; }
}
```

And here's where the grid is being built in the controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetIpdCustomerLicenseGrid([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int id)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    var userRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

    IEnumerable<IpdCustomerLicense> model = _unitOfWork.IpdCustomerLicense.GetCustomerUpsertLicenseManager().Where(x => x.IpdCustomerId == id);
    var types = GetIpdLicenseTypeList();

    var viewModel = model.Select(x =>
                new IpdCustomerLicenseViewModel()
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    LicenseNumber = x.LicenseNumber,
                    IpdCustomerLicenseTypeLookupId = x.IpdCustomerLicenseTypeLookupId,
                    ExpirationDate = x.ExpirationDate,
                    IpdCustomerId = x.IpdCustomerId,
                    UpdateBy = x.UpdateBy,
                    UpdateDateTime = x.UpdateDateTime,
                    InsertDateTime = x.InsertDateTime,
                    InsertBy = x.InsertBy,
        }
    );

    return Json(await viewModel.ToDataSourceResultAsync(request));
}
```

What ends up happening is the field shows up like any standard Int field.

I had also tried using the vm to build a "Display" variable and that showed up properly for data that has been seeded but did not allow for updating and would cause a reference error.

I'm super inexperienced with Kendo and neither myself, nor my supervisors, nor chat gpt have been able to provide a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of this on the Telerik site at https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/editing-custom and I'll detail the steps you'll need to do to accomplish this. On the Telerik demo page, you can click "View Source" and then a list of Files will allow you to view the various files necessary.

1. Create a LicenseType view model that looks something like:

   ```
   public class LicenseTypeViewModel
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Update your IpdCustomerLicenseViewModel to include LicenseTypeViewModel

   ```
   [UIHint("LicenseType")]
   public LicenseTypeViewModel LicenseType { get; set; }
   ```
3. Update your column in your grid definition to be bound to the new LicenseType property in your model with a client template to show the description when not editing

   ```
   columns.Bound(p => p.LicenseType).ClientTemplate("#=LicenseType.Description#").Width(200);
   ```
4. Add a LicenseType.cshtml file to your project that will be used by the grid, the UIHint in step 2 above gives an extra nudge to MVC to get it to find it. (This Kendo example uses the ViewData to bind the list of license types, so if you want to do it that way, you'll need to populate that list in your controller when the view is created)

   ```
   @model [your viewmodels namespace here].LicenseTypeViewModel

   @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
       .DataValueField("ID")
       .DataTextField("Description")
       .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["licensetypes"])
   )
   ```

This should get you on your way...